# Length of multidimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays

i have a simple program for operations with matrixies, but i have a problem -> i have for example array[3][3] and i need some way how to get the number of dimensions- in this case 3, here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int **count()
{
    printf("Write number of rows and collumns in format ROWS space COLLUMNS");
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    scanf("%i %i", &i, &j);
    int **mat1 = (int**)malloc(i*sizeof(int*));
    for (int x = 0; x < j;x++){
        mat1[x] = (int*)malloc(j*sizeof(int));
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < i;x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < j;y++){
            scanf("%i",&mat1[x][y]);
        } 
    }

    printf(Write number of rows and collumns in format ROWS space COLLUMNS");
    int i2 = 0,j2 = 0;
    scanf("%i %i", &i2, &j2);
    int **mat2 = (int**)malloc(i2*sizeof(int*));
    for (int x2 = 0; x2 < j2;x2++){
        mat2[x2] = (int*)malloc(j2*sizeof(int));
    }
    for (int x2 = 0; x2 < i2;x2++){
        for (int y2 = 0; y2 < j2;y2++){
            scanf("%i",&mat2[x2][y2]);
        } 
    }

    int i3 = i, j3 = j; 
    int **mat3 = (int**)malloc(i3*sizeof(int*));
    for (int x = 0; x < j3;x++){
        mat3[x] = (int*)malloc(j3*sizeof(int));
    }

    for (int x3 = 0; x3 < i3;x3++){
        for (int y3 = 0; y3 < j3;y3++){
            mat3[x3][y3] = mat1[x3][y3] + mat2[x3][y3];
        } 
    }
    return mat3;
}

int writeMatrix(int **mat, int rows, int collumns)
{
        int i = rows, j=collumns;
        for (int x = 0; x < i;x++){
            for (int y = 0; y < j;y++){
                printf("%3i ",mat[x][y]);
                }
            printf("\n");
        }
        return 0;
}



int main()
{


    int **m1 = count();
    writeMatrix(m1,x,x);//HERE I NEED TO KNOW NUMBER OF ROWS AND COLLUMNS
    free(m1);
}
```

Here is the code which worked for me in a case of normal array[][] but not in this case -

```
int y = (sizeof(m1)/sizeof(m1[0][0])) / (sizeof(m1)/sizeof(m1[0]));
```

Comment: As the question is tagged C++ prepare for C++ answers, like `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`. Are you sure the question should not be tagged C instead of C++? C solutions would be to move the acquisition of the array dimensions outside of `count()` and pass them in which would also mean the caller can pass them to `writeMatrix()` or pass arguments to `count()` that are populated with the array dimensions or null terminate the dimensions in the array so the end can be detected.

Comment: Be clear , Do u want the answer in C or c++ . Your code seems to be in c but u have taged the question as c++ . The best answer in c++ is 'std::vector<std::vector<int>>'

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a multidimensional array if you don't knwo statically the size of the first dimension, you'll need a jagged array (an array of arrays), as you did it.

And then you can still get the number of allocated rows and columns. Change the `count` prototype to:

```
int** count(int& rows, int& columns)
```

and in it do these assignments (after you've read the values of i and j):

```
rows = i;
columns = j;
```

And call `count` from `main` like this:

```
int rows;
int columns;
int** m1 = count(rows, columns);
```

Then you can call writeMatrix:

```
writeMatrix(m1, rows, columns);
```

BTW, unless you're doing this for educational purposes, you should use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` (or some similar array class), not int**.

Comment: Well yes, i am doing it for education purposes - to learn myself work with pointers, so i dont want to use vectors at all. Is there some way how to do it?